# Display pages inside post loop by category ID

Tags: wordpress, loops

I've figured a way to enable adding categories to a PAGE (not a post). And I was just wondering if there was a way to display PAGES in a post loop, this is my code:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=540'); ?>
```

```
                            <div class="blog_module">


                                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150));
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<img class="alignleft" src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/empty_150_150_thumb.gif" width="150" height="150" />';
                                            }
                                            ?>


                                            <div class="entry">
                                                <h3 class="blog_header"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                <a class="button_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>

                                            </div>  


                                    </div>
```

However, this displays:
[image]

Which isn't what I want, it ONLY DISPLAYS POSTS and not the pages I have assigned to Category ID 540.

Please could someone help with a loop that would display pages that have been assigned to a category.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure its easy. I guess the following should work (untested):

```
query_posts(array('cat'=>540,'post_type'=>page));
```

You can also use WP_Query which is more flexible than query_posts:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>540,'post_type'=>page));

while($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();
// your post here
endwhile;
```

This should be even more flexible:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => 540
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you need posts AND pages try this:

> 'post_type' => 'any'

All information you need you can find on these links: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query